# How can I enable VNC as remote desktop in Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: 22.04, remote-desktop, vnc, 22.10

I want to access my Ubuntu 22.10 machine via VNC, in Ubuntu 22.04 there was an option to use `VNC` instead of the `ms-rd` protokol.

22.04
[image: remote desktop settings in Ubuntu 22.04]

In 22.10 this `enable Legacy VNC Protocol` checkbox is missing does someone know how I can enable it again?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question.
The problem is that Wayland would prevent any other VNC software to work.
Luckily, we can easily disable Wayland upon Ubuntu 22.04 or 22.10 startup.
But even with Wayland disabled, the enable Legacy VNC Protocol option remains missing
With Wayland disabled, I could install and run X11VNC server successfully.

Sorry, this is not the answer I'd wish to read.
Philippe

Comment: @Pilot6 I think this probably is an answer; it's just that answer is "No"

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, the option to use VNC is no longer available because 22.10 uses Wayland instead of X11